# How to create swap partition/file on a Yocto distribution

Tags: linux, yocto, partitioning, swapfile

I'm trying to create a swap partition/file on my board where a `core-image-minimal` has been installed.

The `fdisk -l` command doesn't show any partition thus I'm not able to figure out which block device I need to use to create a new partition.

Secondly, launchig a `swapon` command on a `swapfile` correctly initialized using `mkswap` will raise an invalid argument error saying that the file contains holes even though I created it using `dd`.

At this point I'm not sure if I can do something like this since the `free` output looks like:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         503304       32108      101108         216      370088      465180
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add any partition to your image, you need to modify the `wks` file that is used for your build.

To get the current `wks` file run :

```
bitbake -e | grep ^WKS_FILE=
```

Then, look for that file in your layers sources.

In that file you can add (example 1GB swap):

```
part swap --ondisk mmcblk0 --size 44 --label swap --fstype=swap --size=1024M --overhead-factor 1
```

For a real example, you can see the raspberry-pi machine swap support commit [here](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/g/yocto/message/47271).

You can use a custom `wks` file and set it to your custom machine conf file:

```
WKS_FILE ?= "custom-image.wks"
```

For detailed info, check the Yocto reference about [wks](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-kickstart).

Comment: so the swapfile solution isn't feasible?

Comment: You can try to create a post installation script, see here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.6.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-post-installation-scripts , or you can create a startup service that creates the `swapfile` and activate it if it is not activate it.